# why can't I call a println after a while in defn body in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a function that looks like,

```
(defn app [server]
  (println "before while...."))
  (while test
    while-body)
  (println "...after while."))
```

However when I call the fn I just see the "before while" at the REPL, and then when the while fails its test, "nil".

If I write a test foo at the repl like

```
(defn foo [] 
  (println "testing before")
  (loop [i 100]
    (when (> i 10)
      (prn i)
      (recur (- i 2))))
  (println "after..."))
```

It works as I'd expect.

I've put the actual code up in a paste here, https://www.refheap.com/paste/12147 , if it helps.

What explains the difference in behavior here?

### edit

Apologies for not trying this before, but this does work at the REPL:

```
(defn bar []
  (let [i (atom 100)]
    (println "before...")
    (while (> @i 10)
      (swap! i dec))
    (println "after...")))
```

So there's something else going on.

### edit #2

Testing more at the repl, if I comment out the while loop, the println before and after will print. I was mistaken before about the 'nil', this is the return value of a different function called after the while was called. So it seems to have something to do with the while loop.

I noticed that if I change the while to this

```
(loop []
  (if test
    (do things and recur...)
    (println "test failed")))
```

The "test failed" never prints to the repl.

Comment: yes, there's something funny going on in relation to the future-call I'm making...however I did just check if the test was false *after* the while terminates, and it is.

Comment: Are you sure the while loop is actually terminating? My other suggestion would be to put a (flush) after the final (println) as it might be getting buffered somewhere.

Comment: @Alex, thank you, you gave me the hint I needed. The problem was buried in a different function (a select call which had no timeout). The select was blocking, so my shutdown function wasn't cleaning up properly.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extranious ) at the end of the first println.

```
(defn app [server]
  (println "before while....")
  (while test
    while-body)
  (println "...after while."))
```

But since this is obviously example code that you didn't run, I expect the problem to be in the code that you *did* run. Please copy & paste *that* code exactly as is if this doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't what I thought it was. I was blocking on a select call (called in the while loop) and that was causing problems with my shutdown function which ended the while loop. Adding a timeout to the select fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

In Clojure function definitions, the last thing to be evaluated is what's returned, and (println ...) returns nil

Comment: why would the println itself not print its argument to the repl though?